# iOS8 and Xcode - How to distribute an embedded framework with cocoa pod dependencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I need to create a **compiled** framework for distribution to third parties.

I am using `cocoa-pods` to handle **my** dependencies.

In order to accomplish this, it would seem that that creating a dynamic linked framework is the best option, but I am not sure and open to suggestions.

The steps I took are:

1. I created a wrapper project to contain the framework target
2. Inside the wrapper project I added a new target "Cocoa touch framework" - "MyFramework"
3. All of the relevant code is added to the target
4. Added import statements to the .h file of the framework per the generated comment // In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import
5. Created a podfile - "pod init"
6. Added the **framework** dependencies to the podfile

The podfile looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'Wrapper' do

end

target 'InnerFramework' do
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
end
```

I need to distribute the framework using the "`InnerFramework`" target.

This is where I get stuck -

The framework needs to contain all of the pod dependencies as well as be able to run in a simulator and on an actual device (From the customer perspective)-
The framework also needs to be compliant with app store submission rules , i.e. arm 64bit etc.

The end user can have no access to the original source code - so I can't expect them to recompile.

The end user may also be using `AFNetworking` , and it may be a different version , i.e. "1.0"

When I tried to integrate the framework to a test project I got runtime exceptions as well as compile time errors (depending on the flags I set in the build rules).

I've tried to copy the framework into a test project

Then in "Build phases" I added "Copy files" and add "Inner framework" with check box next to "Code sign on copy"

I get error "Could not build module 'InnerFramework'"

if I import the framework header to the test project code

If I don't import the framework header I get a runtime crash

Comment: Hi. I am interested in solving a similar problem. Did you find a solution to this afterall?

Comment: Not the  best solution (So leaving the question open...) but what I am doing is `pod install --no-integrate` and then manually adding the framework references. If necessary replacing class names to avoid naming collisions.