# Xcode: create Framework with pod dependecies

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, frameworks

I create a framework that use AFNetworking (installed with pod).

I can import this framework on my project and I can use all classes/methods that I exposed, so project compile.

When I try to run project on simulator, I obtain this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F56F98F0-2AE0-4C87-AC9A-6E3B449762D1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BFA5359F-8FCE-4402-8487-CD9C002CB673/MyProject.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
>   Reason: image not found

I already included 'MyFramework' under:

```
Build phases -> Embed Frameworks
```

I suppose I missing something on building Frameworks, but I can find out what! I already seen this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593188/ios8-and-xcode-how-to-distribute-an-embedded-framework-with-cocoa-pod-dependen).

Who can I use MyFramework without installing Pod on MyProject again?

Comment: If your framework uses other pod dependencies you have to create your framework as pod too

Comment: really? Can you link me any sources?

Comment: I can't find some good guide for you, but I can advice to look on other frameworks that uses other pods. For example: https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper 
Pay attention to .podspec file. Framework from example above have dependencies (other pods) described in .podspec file

Comment: @LucaDavanzo did you find a way to do this ?

Comment: @LucaDavanzo did you find the solution to the problem ?

Comment: If it helps anyone, the solution mentioned by @ArtyomDevyatov does work. The trick is that you have to add `s.dependency` in podspec file.

Answer (score 3):

It is really delayed, for this issue but I have got my project working. It might not be the best way but it works. I am putting it here for future reference.

I wanted to do it without using Pods in the main project. The reasoning is, we are bundling our SDK into a framework.

So essentially, the first step I took was to get the framework project bundling without using the workspace. I just dragged the Pods project into the framework project.

[image: File structure]

Then I added the frameworks the the pods project creates and add them to my framework. I set them to optional and code sign. You can see them in the picture of where I added them under the build phases.

[image: Build Phases]

Then add them to your main project. not the framework the normal way by adding the project and or the framework. Then add it to the Embedded binaries and Linked Frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, the solution mentioned by @ArtyomDevyatov does work. The trick is that you have to add 's.dependency' in podspec file.